# Why is spacing off when I write to CSV?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to create a csv using python. In each row, I want the first cell to be a person who asked a question, the second to be a person who answered, and the third to be the time the answer was posted. I'm just creating a simple list where each element of the list is a cell, meaning the list looks like this:

```
Jan Janet 3/4/05
Jason John 3/6/05
...
```

But my output has one letter per cell rather than one word.

Heres's my code:

```
import csv
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

edgelist = []

csv.field_size_limit(1600000)

f = open('/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/harvard/edXresearch/snaCreationFiles/time_series/time_series.csv','rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')

    if line['types'] == 'Question':
        #print 'T'
        source = line['author_id']
    else:
        edgelist.append(source + " " + line['author_id'] + " " + line['time'])

with open("/Users/samuelfinegold/documents/harvard/edxresearch/snacreationfiles/time_series/connections_times_series_ex.csv", "w") as the_file:
    csv.register_dialect("custom", delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(the_file, dialect="custom")
    writer.writerows(edgelist)      

the_file.close()        
f.close()
```

How do I get a csv with a word per cell rather than a letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edgelist` should be a list of lists (or list of tuples), not a list of strings.  Try changing your `edgelist.append()` line to the following:

```
edgelist.append([source, line['author_id'], line['time']])
```

You are currently getting each letter in a column because when you write a row to a csv file it is expecting an iterable where each element is a column.  If you attempt to write a string as a row then each letter in that string will be interpreted as a separate column.  This means that each row should be a list and so `writer.writerows()` requires a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

`.writerows()` expects to have a list of sequences; a list of lists or tuples, really, but strings are sequences too.

Append tuples to `edgelist`:

```
edgelist.append((source + " " + line['author_id'] + " " + line['time'],))
```

Because strings are sequences too, sequences of single characters, you see your `Jan Janet 3/4/05` input being split into separate cells.

What you *really* want, is for `csv` to separate your values though; if you want a space separated list, use:

```
edgelist.append((source, line['author_id'], line['time'],))
```

and tell `csv.writer()` to use spaces as the delimiter:

```
csv.register_dialect("custom", delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: This will put the entire string like `Jan Janet 3/4/05` into one cell.

Comment: @F.J: Sure, but that's what the OP was *doing*. Not in the best way, but still.